# How to Run time command by default when certain commands are run?

Tags: time

Wondering if there is a way to run time command in Linux by default when certain commands are run.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Would an `alias` suffice? e.g. `alias ls='time ls'` (note: may not be a good idea depending on the command and how it is used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may alias the commands that you want to time:

```
alias ls='time command ls'
alias firefox='time command firefox'
```

or, with shell functions:

```
ls ()  { time command ls "$@"; }
firefox ()  { time command firefox "$@"; }
```

The `command` command is not strictly needed in the aliases, but required in the shell function, or otherwise you get a nice infinite recursion that probably ends with a core-dump of the shell.  The `command` command will bypass any shell function lookup for the command you're executing.